# Try/Catch not catching System.Threading.ThreadAbortException in ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, try-catch, threadabortexception

I am trying to export a Crystal ReportDocument using `ExportToHttpResponse` like so:

```
report.ExportToHttpResponse(exportOptions, HttpContext.Current.Response, true, "test");
```

When I first tried to run this, I received a `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`. After reading about how this is a known error with `ExportToHttpResponse` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968194/thread-was-being-aborted-exception-in-crystal-reports), I tried implementing the suggested workaround of wrapping the statement in a try/catch block like so:

```
try
{
    report.ExportToHttpResponse(expOptions, HttpContext.Current.Response, true, "test");
}
catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException e)
{
}
```

As I understand it, this should catch and ignore the error, and proceed. However, I am still getting the `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` on the closing bracket of the catch statement. My question is why is the exception still being received even though I am apparently catching it, and how could I go about fixing it so that the exception is ignored?

Comment: "ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block.". See the remarks section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx

Comment: Where are you seeing these errors?  Are you logging them in a global error handler?  If this is in a global error handler, such as Applicaiton_Error in global.asax, you simply need to filter those out and not do anything with them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can catch the ThreadAbortException and call the [Thread.REsetAbort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort.aspx) method, to cancel the bubbling of the exception.
However, keep in mind that response.end is a bad idea. Whenever you can try to call HttpApplication.CompleteRequest(), and read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) question which proved really useful to me in this regard.

Comment: Thread.ResetAbort did fix my problem, thanks. I am aware that Response.End is a bad idea, but I am not the one calling it in this scenario. Thanks for the additional information as well.