# Crystal Reports methods ExportToHttpResponse and ExportToStream hang and never return

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, reportdocument

The code I'm troubleshooting exports a Crystal Report `ReportDocument` to Excel. Most of the time, the export works just fine. Unfortunately for some datasets, the `ExportToHttpResponse` method never returns and causes the app to hang. Eventually there is a *Thread was being aborted* exception along with a request timeout.

Here is the line that hangs:

```
reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.Excel,Response,True, fileName);
```

I also tried using `ExportToStream`  [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968194/thread-was-being-aborted-exception-in-crystal-reports) which also hangs:

```
System.IO.Stream myStream;
byte[] byteArray;
myStream = boReportDocument.ExportToStream (ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

I have tried different export formats, restarting IIS, etc. There seems to be a size limit or perhaps specific data scenarios that cause these methods to hang. Any workarounds or explanations for this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   Public Shared Sub ExportDataSetToExcel(ByVal ds As DataTable, ByVal filename As String)
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        response.Clear()
        response.Buffer = True
        response.Charset = ""
        'response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        'response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & filename & ".xls")

        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                Dim dg As New DataGrid()
                dg.DataSource = ds
                dg.DataBind()
                dg.RenderControl(htw)
                response.Charset = "UTF-8"
                response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())
                response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
                response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

and in your viewer add :

```
DT = New DataTable
DT = (Your Method)
ExportDataSetToExcel(DT, "ExportedReport")
```

also add :

```
 Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    ReportObject.Close()
    ReportObject.Dispose()
End Sub
```

So report would not add restrictions on the number of loaded reports.